# Setting fields with correct default value

Tags: c#, .net

When writing constructors, I regularly encounter a situation where some fields already have approperiate (default) values, such as `false` for boolean values and `0` for integers. What are reasons to emphasize these values, for example like:

`state = 0;`

Do you appreciate it when reading someones code? On one side I feel like expressing implementation details explicitly, on the other side I find it pointless to set a field when I'm sure it is already correct.

Comment: Myself, I tend to do this in C++, but not in C#. Never really thought about why, though.

Comment: Maybe it's because in C++, many types (like `int`) have undefined default value? This is not a problem in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work in a projects company. I LOVE it when default values our explicitly defined in the code. This also implies:
1. Definition of the data - is the data type used correct ?
2. The semantic definition of a value - Like in your example, 0 is a clue for an initial state. In some cases I get no clue what 0 means.

Note :
State MUST be defined somewhere, be it a CONST value, or an enumeration somewhere. The value 0 has no other meaning than initial state. A string literal might add some more value to it.

Comment: I understand the note, its just an example though. I guess a buffer where the initial position is `0` is more realistic.

Answer (score 5):

Just because *you're* sure it is correct, that intern over in the other building has **no** idea. Giving objects a nice sane default is good. Being explicit is good.

And remember, code is there for humans, not computers.

Comment: +1 : Also I don't have to wonder what you were thinking if you are explicit. I might be an expert programmer (yeh...I know.... some of my peers will debate that), I am not a mind reader.  More importantly, I only have interest in succeeding at one of those skills

Comment: Intern or not, any developer must understand default values.

Comment: @LeopoldAsperger - I heartily disagree. I'm pretty sure _I_ couldn't tell you the default values for all of the different variable declarations for all of the different languages I use _today_, let alone know. It's trivia, because they shouldn't be counted on.